# maximum position uncertainty of particle in a box

Tags: mathematical-physics

I want to verify mathematically

for wave function $\psi(x)$ satisfying

$\psi(x)=0$ for $\lvert x \rvert \ge \frac{L}{2} $ and

$\int_{- \frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} \lvert \psi(x) \rvert ^2 dx = 1 $

Below holds

$\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}  x^2 {\lvert \psi(x)\rvert}^2 dx - \left( \int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} x {\lvert \psi(x) \rvert}^2 dx  \right) ^2 \le \frac{L^2}{4} $

I know that the equality holds for ${\lvert \psi(x) \rvert}^2 = \frac{1}{2} \delta (x - \frac{L}{2}) +\frac{1}{2} \delta (x + \frac{L}{2})  $

But.. I dont konw how to establish the inequality

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It seems that you need to solve for the eigenfunctions first.  When you do that, then try computing $\langle X^2\rangle - \langle X\rangle^2$ on $\psi_n(x)$.

Comment: @Mnifldz This holds for any shape of the potential within the requirements of the OP. I don't think you will be able to find the eigenfunctions explicitly.

Comment: Note that only the probability density $|\psi(x)|^2$ is relevant. This result is known as [Popoviciu's inequality on variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popoviciu%27s_inequality_on_variances), see also [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588/variance-of-a-bounded-random-variable).

Answer (score 0):

Given that $\lvert x \rvert \le \frac{L}{2}$ in the range of the integral, $ x^2 \le \frac{L^2}{4}$ and thus

> $ \int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}  x^2 {\lvert \psi(x)\rvert}^2 dx \le \frac{L^2}{4} \overbrace{\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} {\lvert \psi(x)\rvert}^2 dx}^{1} \le \frac{L^2}{4} . $

Substracting any positive number, like $\left( \int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} x {\lvert \psi(x) \rvert}^2 dx  \right) ^2$, from the LHS will preserve the inequality.

The equality holds iff

$ \int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}  x^2 {\lvert \psi(x)\rvert}^2 dx = \frac{L^2}{4}$

**and**

$\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} x {\lvert \psi(x) \rvert}^2 dx = 0.$

I wonder if the function you gave is the only case of equality.